# Excel - Reverse order of rows in Named Range

Tags: sorting, excel, excel-2007, range, vba

I've got these Named Ranges that work fine. But they are reversed from the get go because of how data is imported into the worksheet, and I need to re-reverse them again.

The named range looks like this:

```
=OFFSET(Numbers1!$D$2;0;0;SUMPRODUCT(IF(Numbers1!$D$2:$D$60<>"";1;0));1)
```

So is this possible by only altering the formula?

"Reversed" means that it looks like this in the spreadsheet:

```
201103
201102
201101
201012
201011
201010
201009
201008
201007
201006
201005
201004
201003
201002
201001
200912
```

What I'm after is to reverse the order so that the number at the bottom (200912) comes at the top, etc etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "reversed"? What's reversed in that formula?

Comment: Nothing. The data is imported reversed, and it's via a macro that I don't have access to. The data itself doesn't "know" it's reversed, so I'd like to reverse it.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "reversed"? Written right-to-left inside each cell? Cells order flipped right-left or upside-down? Repeating "reversed" over and over doesn't help us understand.

Comment: Well, the range takes the whole column D from row 1 to 60. And they are sorted in the wrong order because of how the data are imported. I'm creating a graph from this range and I want it reversed to it will look correct. Instad of it going 10,9,8,7,6 etc, I want it to go 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc. Edit: Check the updated post.

Comment: Got it. See answer. As an aside, what are you doing with `SUMPRODUCT(IF(Numbers1!$D$2:$D$60<>"";1;0))`? (Presumably in an array?) Doesn't this just do the same as `COUNT`?

Comment: It has to be there because the Named Range is supposed to ignore values that are 0 or nothing. If I don't use SUMPRODUCT, the graph ends up including values that are nothing. That's why I even use a Named Range in the first place actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this formula e.g. in cell E2 and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNT(D2:D$60)<1,"",OFFSET(D$2,COUNT(D2:D$60)-1,0))
```

The result is the same numerical values as at the top of D2:D60 but in reverse order.

Comment: Aha, but remember, this isn't a formula I enter in a cell. It's in a Named Range. Also, the SUMPRODUCT has to be there because the Named Range shouldn't include values that are Nothing. So far, SUMPRODUCT seems to be the only solution for this right now. Edit: Also, the formula in the named range has to be similar to the formula mentioned in the first post. =OFFSET(Numbers1!$D$2;0;0;SUMPRODUCT(IF(Numbers1!$D$2:$D$60<>"";1;0));1)

Comment: Yeah, but can't you start by flipping the order of the numerical values that were "reversed from the get go", and then make your Named Range formula refer to this new flipped data instead of the original data in the wrong order?

Comment: That would probably mean changing the formula in the cells instead of the Named Range. The formula in each cell looks like this:
=IF(Numbers1!$E$2<>0;Numbers1!$A$2;""). The Numbers1 is the sheet I'm picking the values from btw.

Comment: Look, it's impossible for me to tell you exactly what to write in each cell when I can't see where things are in your spreadsheet. Can't you start with those imported values in the wrong order, flip their order using the formula in the answer so they're in the right order, and then carry on with all the rest using those properly-ordered values?

Comment: I could do that, if I knew what the formulas in the cells would look like. The formula you wrote in the answer doesn't work either. So I can't imagine how the formulas would even look like. I guess I could just reverse the axis of the graphs themselves. Although I'll have to do a lot of customizing to get it right. But that's possibility.

Comment: FYI the formula I wrote in the answer works fine. I tested it. In your language edition of Excel, you may need to use `;` instead of `,`.